# Facebook app links in Android not working from my test server

Tags: android, facebook, applinks

I'm trying to test app links for my application without success.
I created on my dev machine a simple IIS web application with a test.html page containing:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.test.debug">
        <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="test">
    </head>
    <body>
     <H1>123</H1>
    </body>
</html>
```

in my AndroidManifast.xml I've inserted the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now from the android device's browser I go to the url in my dev machine. i.e http://10.1.10.125/testFB/test.html, and share the page.

Then from the wall of my facebook app i click the link. but the app doesn't open - it shows the web page in the internal webview.

I also tried using the schema(copied from facebook documentation) without success.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The webpage must be publicly accessible (and crawled by Facebook), that's the only way that Facebook will know about the metadata.

Comment: Thanks @MingLi for your reply. I moved my test page to a public server and still the page opens in facebook internal browser. 
Is there something I need to do to make facebook crawl the page?

Comment: You can use the url debugger to see if your meta tags are being crawled properly by FB. See https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Did you work out what was going on with this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @WillCalderwood no yet.

Comment: perhaps i came here too late . But i just configured the applinks to work . message me if anyone needs some aid

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib it will be great if you can write an answer as to what needs to be done. I moved to other stuff, but will sure come back to this soon. And also for others that are having the same problem